# Removing sound effects from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am building a website in Wordpress with the theme called 'Werkstatt'. In their theme demo they got sound effects enabled: for instance, when u tab the menu button, tab.mp3 starts playing and you hear a tab sound. Now you got the option to disable these sound effects, but for some reason the effects are still loading when I load my page:

[Loading sound effects on page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRSFk.png)

Also, by tabbing the hamburger-menu on my iPhone the music player starts playing:

[iPhone player when pressing menu button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzApy.png)

Is there any way to disable these sound effects from loading manually? This is the code in where the .mp3's are loaded:

```
var themeajax = {"url":"http:\/\/..\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","l10n":{"loading":"Loading ...","nomore":"No More Posts","added":"Added To Cart","added_svg":"<svg xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 64 64\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 64 64\"><path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000\" stroke-width=\"2\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"m13 33l12 12 24-24\"\/><\/svg>"},"sounds":{"music_sound":"off","music_sound_toggle_home":"on","music_sound_file":"http:\/\/..\/wp-content\/themes\/werkstatt\/assets\/sounds\/music_sound.mp3","menu_item_hover_sound":"off","menu_item_hover_sound_file":"http:\/\/..\/wp-content\/themes\/werkstatt\/assets\/sounds\/hover.mp3","menu_open_sound":"off","menu_open_sound_file":"http:\/\/..\/wp-content\/themes\/werkstatt\/assets\/sounds\/open.mp3","menu_close_sound":"off","menu_close_sound_file":"http:\/\/..\/wp-content\/themes\/werkstatt\/assets\/sounds\/close.mp3","click_sound":"off","click_sound_file":"http:\/\/..\/wp-content\/themes\/werkstatt\/assets\/sounds\/click.mp3"}};
```

```html
<?php

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Here we have all the custom functions for the theme
    Please be extremely cautious editing this file.
    You have been warned!

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Define Theme Name for localization
define('THB_THEME_ROOT', get_template_directory_uri());
define('THB_THEME_ROOT_ABS', get_template_directory());

// Option-Tree Theme Mode
add_filter( 'ot_show_pages', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'ot_show_new_layout', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'ot_theme_mode', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'ot_override_forced_textarea_simple', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'ot_google_fonts_api_key', function() { return 'AIzaSyA_sfIukXUl1YF8tpjXNGOvpYKNDnFKwFM'; } );
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/ot-radioimages.php';
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/ot-metaboxes.php';
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/ot-themeoptions.php';
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/ot-functions.php';
if ( ! class_exists( 'OT_Loader' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() .'/admin/ot-loader.php';
}

// TGM Plugin Activation Class
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require get_template_directory() .'/inc/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
    require get_template_directory() .'/inc/plugins.php';
}

// Misc
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/misc.php';

// Script Calls
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/script-calls.php';

// CSS Output of Theme Options
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/selection.php';

// Add Menu Support
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/wp3menu.php';

// Enable Sidebars
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/sidebar.php';

// Ajax
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/ajax.php';

// Portfolio Related
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/portfolio-related.php';

// Visual Composer Integration
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/visualcomposer.php';

// WPML Support
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/wpml.php';

// WooCommerce Support
require get_template_directory() .'/inc/woocommerce.php';

// WordPress Importer
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/import.php';
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/one-click-demo-import/one-click-demo-import.php';
}


// Defer Javascripts
// Defer jQuery Parsing using the HTML5 defer property
if (!(is_admin() )) {
    function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        // return "$url' defer ";
        return "$url' defer onload='";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has modified question text to 'Please delete please delete [...]'

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to modify that line of JS code? If so, NULLing out the file values ought to work...

```
var themeajax = {"url":"http:\/\/..\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","l10n":{"loading":"Loading ...","nomore":"No More Posts","added":"Added To Cart","added_svg":"<svg xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 64 64\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 64 64\"><path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000\" stroke-width=\"2\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"m13 33l12 12 24-24\"\/><\/svg>"},
"sounds":{"music_sound":"off","music_sound_toggle_home":"on","music_sound_file": NULL,"menu_item_hover_sound":"off","menu_item_hover_sound_file": NULL,"menu_open_sound":"off","menu_open_sound_file": NULL,"menu_close_sound":"off","menu_close_sound_file": NULL,"click_sound":"off","click_sound_file": NULL}};
```

Comment: I don't know.. Got this from inspect mode in Safari. Been looking for this file for a long time but I still didn't manage to find it.

Comment: Worth a look in theme's `functions.php` file?

Comment: I'd have to look at the theme files to see where it's being added. I assume you've disabled the sounds using Theme Options per the documentation? Looks like another user has reported problems with audio still enabled after disabling, too...

Comment: Yes, disabled them by using the theme documentation. If you like to you can see the files over teamviewer / Skype?

Answer (score 0):

according to the theme's author, you can toggle the sounds in the Theme Options under Appearance. 3rd question down on this page.. ctrl+f "sound"  https://themeforest.net/item/werkstatt-creative-portfolio-theme/17870799/comments?page=5

Comment: Yes I know.. I was about to put a screenshot of that panel in here but since this account is new I could only upload up to 2 images. But I've disabled every sound: [link](http://i65.tinypic.com/fx5l4i.png). Even after disabling them, my browser still loads the sound effects for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to create a child theme in order to change the enqeue_scripts function from your main theme that includes the javascript for the sound to play.

Can you paste the functions.php of your main theme to see where the enqeueing takes place ?

Comment: Pasted the functions.php in my post